# Javascript to refresh multiple windows after window.open has run

Tags: javascript

I have a number of url's for quick testing a REST API that I am running using window.open. to launch each call in a separate window. Each window has a 1 second delay before it opens.
However as there is some intermittent latency on the servers I need to refresh the windows after they have run.

I have tried to figure out how to use I tried using both: `window.location.reload(true);` and `setTimeout(refresh, 5000);`

But I'm not sure how to get the refresh to work on each window as per below.

This is what I am currently running:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myWindow1 = window.open('http://xxx','mywindow1','width=200,height=200'); 
}, 0000);

setTimeout(function() {
    myWindow2 = window.open('http://xxx','mywindow2','width=200,height=200'); 
}, 0000);

setTimeout(function() {
    myWindow3 = window.open('http://xxx','mywindow3','width=200,height=200'); 
}, 0000);
```

Comment: Why do you have `0000` instead of just `0`?

Answer (score 2):

Because they're cross-origin, you probably **can't** refresh them.

If you can in your environment, this is how:

```
myWindow1.reload(true);
```

...at the time you want it to happen (which is obviously **after** your timer callback has run and opened the window, so `myWindow1` has a value). For instance, if you want to refresh it 20 seconds after you opened it:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myWindow1 = window.open('http://xxx','mywindow1','width=200,height=200'); 
    setTimeout(function() {
        myWindow1.reload(true);
    }, 20000);
}, 0000);
```